# How can I insulate an already converted attic space?

Tags: drywall, insulation, attic

A couple of years ago we had our attic converted to a spare bedroom,  It became obvious after the first winter that there was a problem, after inspection it was confirmed that there is no insulation at all,  my question is, what is the best way to rectify this? i am hoping that I  can apply some sort of insulated plaster board over the existing board but really i'm clueless, any advice would be really appreciated,  ps. cost is a big factor for me at the moment.  thanks Audrey

Comment: Does the bedroom ceiling go all the way up to the top of the attic space?

Comment: If your attic ceiling is attached directly to the roof framing, your options are limited. There may be no way around ripping it out, and just starting over. There needs to be adequate airflow, between the insulation, and the roof decking. On the other hand, any insulating and drywall/plaster work, that you may do over the top of what is there now, would also be just as cost invasive as just ripping it out and doing it correctly. Any pictures that you may have, of the space prior to the the conversion, and even of the exterior roof line would help a lot too.